# Too many RxCachedScheduler Thread and okHttp Task runner thread in Waiting state

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, okhttp, micronaut

We have our service developed using the micronaut framework. Earlier we had default configuration for EventLoop with 20 threads. We were noticing a lot of thread were going in blocking state. As we can see in the below image.

[image]

After doing some analysis found that since our client calls were taking time, we should create separate eventloop for the client calls. As per the micronaut documenation : https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#clientConfiguration -> section 7.1 -> Configuring Event Loop Groups . We updated our configuration as below :

```
  http:
    client:
      event-loop-group: client
      read-timeout: 5m
      timeout: 5m
      max-content-length: '100MB'
  netty:
    event-loops:
      default:
        num-threads: 25
        prefer-native-transport: true
      client:
        num-threads: 25
        prefer-native-transport: true
```

With the above configuration, we noticed that we see very few RxCachedThreadScheduler thread , wehereas we are seeing a lot of OkHttp task Runner thread in blocking state. I am not able to understand how this all process is working and why did we saw very less RxCachedThreadScheduler threads and so many OkHttp task runner thread in blocking state.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How many instances of OkHttpClient are you creating? If it's more than 1 that could cause some performance problems because threads and connections aren’t reused as aggressively as they could be.

(Using `OkHttpClient.newBuilder()` is fine; that shares resources with the source OkHttpClient.)

Comment: We are not using OkHttpClient in our code anywhere, not able to figure from where these OkHttpThread are bing created

Comment: Consider auditing your 3rd party libraries. Something is using OkHttp.